# How to loop through data in a SwiftData model

Tags: swift, swift-data

I am trying to loop through data saved in a SwiftData model in a function, do some cleanup and selective add that data to a different SwiftData model.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this basic loop through via swift.  I don't want to do this in a list on a screen but by a function I can trigger to run against the data.  Here is what I've tried but

```
func updateTripData() {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var locationDataSD: [LocationDataSD]
    
    var locations: [LocationDataSD]
    var index = 0
    while index < locations.count {
        print(locations[index].timestamp, locations[index].latitude, locations[index].latitude)
    }
}
```

I get an error

```
Cannot find '_locationDataSD' in scope
```

Comment: you cannot have `@Environment` and `@Query` in a function, they are only for use inside/by a `View`.

Comment: You have an `@Environment` variable and an `@Query` variable inside a function?  How does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access SwiftData outside of a view in a function then you need to pass a ModelContext (or ModelContainer) object to that function since you cannot use property wrappers like @Environment and @Query outside of a view.

And since you can't use @Query you will need to use a FetchDescriptor when fetching data.

```
func updateTripData(using context: ModelContext) throws {
    let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<LocationDataSD>()
    let locations = try context.fetch(fetchDescriptor)

    for location in locations {
        //perform updates
    }
}
```

If you like minimised code the above can be written as

```
try context.fetch(FetchDescriptor<LocationDataSD>()).forEach { location in
     //perform updates
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Environment` and `@Query` are only meaningful inside a `View`.

Declare `@Query var locationDataSD: [LocationDataSD]` in your `View`, then
pass the data to the function that is presumably in a separate class, such as:

```
func updateTripData(locationDataSD: [LocationDataSD]) {
    locationDataSD.forEach { location in
        print("----> \(location.timestamp)  \(location.latitude)  \(location.longitude) ")
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

If your function is in a `View`, then just do this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext  // <--- here
    @Query private var locationDataSD: [LocationDataSD]   // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        // ....
        Button("do updateTripData") {
            updateTripData() // <--- here
        }
        // ....
    }
    
    func updateTripData() {
        locationDataSD.forEach { location in
            print("----> \(location.timestamp)  \(location.latitude)  \(location.longitude) ")
        }
    }
}
```